# MySQL: Fastest query to determine that table has at least one row?

Tags: mysql, performance

What would be the fastest query, to check that table is not empty (has at least one row)?

Comment: `SELECT id FROM tbl LIMIT 1`?

Comment: Are you asking me?

Comment: Probably, `SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM tbl` ? Can you explain why your query is fastest?

Comment: If `tbl` uses `MyISAM` they probably are equally fast. `MyISAM` stores the number of rows in the table. If `tbl` uses the `InnoDB` storage engine, `COUNT(*)` is not that fast because it doesn't store the number of rows in the table; it really counts them everytime `COUNT(*)` is present in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COUNT(...)` requires scanning the table.  Not fast.  (MyISAM is an exception.)

`SELECT id FROM tbl LIMIT 1` is not bad, but it returns some junk.

`EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM tbl )` returns true/false (1/0) in (I think) the fastest way.